# Why does this loop in another thread fail to terminate?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I am using .NET Framework version 4.7.2.

I created a `bool` variable called `threadState`. This variable tells the thread, `draw`, to exit, but even if you make the variable `false` the thread does not terminate. Variables and labels in functions put in a thread are not used by any thread other than this one.

Thread code:

```csharp
private void drawReadPoint()
{
    while (threadState)
    {
        RxReadLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
        {
            RxReadLabel.Text = "▼" + _rx.queue.readIdx.ToString();
            readPoint.X = Convert.ToInt32(map(_rx.queue.readIdx, 0, _rx.maxSize, 0, 1100) + 28);
            readPoint.Y = 1;
            RxReadLabel.Location = readPoint;
        }
        );
        RxWriteLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
        {
            RxWriteLabel.Text = "△" + _rx.queue.readIdx.ToString();
            writePoint.X = Convert.ToInt32(map(_rx.queue.writeIdx, 0, _rx.maxSize, 0, 1100) + 28);
            writePoint.Y = 29;
            RxWriteLabel.Location = writePoint;
        }
        );
        richTextBox_log.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { richTextBox_log.AppendText("중"); });
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    richTextBox_log.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { richTextBox_log.AppendText("끝!!"); });
}
```

Closing code:

```csharp
private void FormMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    threadState = false;
    richTextBox_log.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { richTextBox_log.AppendText("시작"); });
    draw.Join();
    richTextBox_log.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { richTextBox_log.AppendText("진짜 끝"); });
    readqThread.Abort();
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        Dispose();
        e.Cancel = false;
    }));
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: You don't have to worry about richTextBox related code.
I'm sorry.

Comment: After setting `threadState` to `false`, does `drawReadPoint()` just keep appending to `richTextBox_log`, or what happens?  Also, you're calling `Application.Exit()`, which raises `FormClosing` events, from a `FormClosing` event handler.  `Thread.Abort()` is [best avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort#remarks), too.

Comment: If you want to cancel another task / thread, you should create a `CancellationTokenSource` so you can `while(!token.IsCancellationRequested) ... await Task.Delay(1000, token); ` which will exit the loop quickly. Or just create a timer.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who informed me.
However, I couldn't use these methods because other codes would cause problems.
I am sorry that I can only write part of the code because it is not possible to disclose the code.
However, it was modified in a different way.
thank you.

Comment: After setting threadState to false, does drawReadPoint() just keep appending to richTextBox_log, or what happens? Also, you're calling Application.Exit(), which raises FormClosing events, from a FormClosing event handler. Thread.Abort() is best avoided, too.____________________________________________
cannot be added.

Comment: Could you include in the question the definition of the `threadState` and the `readqThread`?